# How to change image for UIButton after user click on Done button is another UIView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

When the user clicks on a `UIButton` on tableview ( tableview has mutiple button in each row), another View is shown. 
I want to change image for this button after the user has clicked on the Done button of the other UIView. How can I do that? I'm a newbie. Could you please provide some code for me? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE CODE:

Code for tableview :

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UIButton *market = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [market addTarget:self action:@selector(marketPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [market setTag:3000];
        [market setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 6, 30, 30)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:market];

    }

   for (UIButton *button in [cell subviews]) { // change name of table here
    if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        button.tag = indexPath.row;
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}


    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    _tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0);

    return cell;
}
```

Code for Open button ( button that user click on to show another View)

```
    - (void)marketPressedAction:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    buttontag = button.tag;
    NSLog(@"Market button click at row %d",buttontag);
}
```

And code for Done button:

```
 -(void)submitMarket
{
    for (UIButton *button in [_tableView subviews]) { // change name of table here
        if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            if (button.tag == buttontag) {
                [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarketplaceSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Are you saying when the user clicks a button, a new UIView is presented, then when the user clicks another button on the new UIView you want to change the image of the original button on the original view?

Comment: Your view is in same controller or different controller?

Comment: @SamkitJain: my view is in same controller

Comment: Lets chat here I may help u http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35495/for-user-2669713

Comment: Sorry because i don't enough 20 reputation, so i can not chat with you :(. I updated my code. pls help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:someImge forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Code on button click :

```
 savedTag = button.tag;
```

Code on Done button click :

```
for (UIButton *button in [table subviews]) { // change name of table here 
  if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) { 
    if (button.tag == savedtag) { 
       [button setBackgroundImage:someImge forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } 
  } 
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath in place of this : `[market setTag:3000];` write `[market setTag:indexPath.row];`

Try this :

Replace :

```
marketButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3000];
[marketButton setTag:indexPath.row];
```

With this :

```
for (UIButton *button in [cell subviews]) { // change name of table here
     if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
         button.tag == indexPath.row; 
     }
}
```

One more thing : make first line of cellForRowAtIndexPath as :

`NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tableCell";`

Change your cellForRowAtIndexPath as :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UIButton *market = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [market addTarget:self action:@selector(marketPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [market setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [market setTag:indexPath.row];
        [market setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 6, 30, 30)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:market];

    }

    else {

       for (UIButton *button in [cell subviews]) { // change name of table here
         if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            button.tag = indexPath.row;
         }
    }
}


    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    _tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks but my case , tableview has mutiple button in each row. How can i do that ?

Comment: I used this code to get tag for each button when click on :  - (void)marketPressedAction:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    buttontag = button.tag;
    NSLog(@"Market button click at row %d",buttontag);

    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    }
    else {

            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarketplaceSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [sender setSelected:YES];
        }
    }
}

Comment: I updated my code in my question. please check it. thanks much

Comment: for (UIButton *button in [cell subviews]) { // change name of table here
        if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            button.tag = indexPath.row;
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }

Comment: I have changed in your question . See and try that it will help

Comment: Do you show me your change? It still not show image when tableview load at first time

Comment: Copy and paste my cellForRowAtIndexPath and try

Comment: I tried your cellForRowAtIndexPath but it can not show image for UIButton, but when click on uibutton it show another UIView

Answer (score 0):

You can set another image for **selected state** of your button and after click on Done button just **set selected state** your button.

```
  [yourButton setBackgroundImage:someImge forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

after Done button:

```
  [yourButton setSelected:YES];
```

Or if you use before `UIControlStateSelected` you can also use any other state. Or even users state - `UIControlStateApplication`

Comment: Thanks but if tableview has mutiple UIButton, then click on them, will show anotherView ???

Comment: I think You need to create custom UITableViewCell and manage your buttons inside. on layoutSubViews set the image you need for current cell state

Answer (score 0):

you can use a delegate or a NSNotificationCenter,
in your view where is Done button, you need create a property

```
  @property (weak, nonatomic) <protocol_name> delegate;
```

and in your action method for DoneButton, you need to send a message to that delegate

```
[self.delegate method_name];
```

and the other view will be set as delegate for this one

`[viewWithDoneButton setDelegate:self];

and you need to implement the delegate method `