# Change view(UIimage,UIButton) when tap another UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to change the image of a view when i am tapping a UIButton, i mean the same behavior Highlighted or Selected but applied to another view(UIButton image).

f.e:

```
 [self.imgCheckFacebook setBackgroundImage: 
                   [UIImage imageWithColor: [UIColor blue]] 
                                   forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

This is ok when i am tapping the imgCheckFacebook but i want this behavior when i am tapping another button or view.

Comment: Your question has [already been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247704/how-to-change-image-for-uibutton-after-user-click-on-done-button-is-another-uivi) and [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801819/uibutton-image-doesnt-change-when-tapped) in many other questions here.

Comment: That is not my problem, it solved "after" is pressed, i want when is pressing(UIControlStateSelected) and go to normal state when the button is in UIControlStateNormal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now that I understand your question a little bit better.

Maybe you just need to fire events at the right time?

How about using `[yourFirstButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`?

And if UIControlEventTouchUpInside doesn't work, you could try other possible event types (listed in [UIControl's Control Events section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events)).